# Sliding zoom with mobile sdk in mavic pro 2

Tags: dji-sdk

is there any way to slide zoom with mobile sdk in mavic pro 2
and there no information for WaypointActionType.CAMERA_ZOOM in API doc

Answer (score -1):

mavic2 pro should not support zoom，mavic2 zoom support zoom